# What tools can I use to design for Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich)?

Tags: android, wireframe, mockup

I have to create a few prototypes (Balsamiq style) for Android 4.0 (ICS). I tried looking into tools etc from previous questions and from Google, but nothing seems to work for me.

What tools can I use to design for Android 4.0?

Comment: I take it you have looked into the Android Design Guide? http://developer.android.com/design/ This might not be exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: +1 to the Android Design site. In the "Downloads" section you'll find stencils for various design tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned above the [Android Design Guide](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html) is a good place to start.

If you are aiming at a more rough and sketchy prototype like the ones seen in [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/), you should really try to draw some sketches using pen and paper.

Many people are scared of picking up the sketchpad, my tip would be to have a real interface or even Balsamiq near by to be inspired from. It does not have to be more complex than to achieve good results from an early prototyping study.

Answer (score 9):

I personally am a big fan of Axure for rapid medium fidelity prototyping and I really like the fact that you have so many widgets you can pull in to create decently high fidelity mockups

- [Android Library for Axure prototyping](http://giridhar.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/android-library-for-axure-prototyping/)

However for creating high fidelity and production level mockups,my tool of choice is Photoshop

- [Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich design startkit](http://www.androiddesign.info/)
- [Android GUI high fidelity PSD's](http://www.teehanlax.com/downloads/android-gui-psd-high-density/)

I am not sure what is the level of fidelity you are looking for but this [User Interface guidelines document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html) from Android might be helpful

Comment: Android Library looks outdated in 2018.

Comment: @naXa You do realize this question was answered in 2012 right.

Answer (score 1):

dotmartin's link at the top is probably the most comprehensive: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Good resources for older versions below, BTW:

http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/10/android-app-developers-gui-kits-icons-fonts-and-tools/

I personally use Fireworks for comps, prototypes and wireframes etc. I'm a big fan of it after switching from Photoshop 4 years ago. Fireworks, if you are not familiar, is like a light weight, nimble version of Photoshop. Its 'page' and 'state' features allow rapid development of multiple screen comps. Integration with Illustrator and Photoshop is fairly good too.

Comment: They're not specifically for version 4.0

Comment: yes, good call carora3, apologies all.
dotmartin's link at the top is probably the most comprehensive: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Comment: Android Design Guide doesn't have a set of stencils. That's what the OP is asking.

Comment: @dnbrv Yes, there are some stencils here: http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your response, Although there'S no particular tool for this, but for the time being [Android Design Downloads](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) seem the most plausible option.

Answer (score 0):

WireframeSketcher comes with a [stencil for Android Ice Cream Sandwich](http://wireframesketcher.com/mockups/android-ice-cream-sandwich.html) which is loosely based on wireframing templates provided by Android design team. This stencil can be used both for Android phone and tablet apps. It includes common controls, dialogs, action bars, lists and menus. There is also a Browser control for those who want to wireframe their website for tablets.

Note that I am the developer of WireframeSketcher.